# Could not find default endpoint element that references contract... but service is working

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I started learning MVVM and I ran into a problem. When I hover over the LoansGridView, I get

"Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'LoanService.ILoansDbMethods' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element."

This breaks my designer. However, when I run the project, the service works as expected - grid is populated with data.

[image: Designer]

This is my MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Client.Mvvm.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Client.Mvvm.ViewModels"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Client.Mvvm.Views"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="640"
    Height="600"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<views:LoansGridView />
```

This is the relevant part of my app.config

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior >
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="10000000"/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ILoansDbMethods" />
   </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
        <client>
   <endpoint address="http://localhost:43592/Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ILoansDbMethods" contract="LoanService.ILoansDbMethods"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_ILoansDbMethods" />
  </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

I have looked at similar questions, but I think my problem is somehow different, since I can actually connect to the service. 
I have tried:

- updating my service reference
- adding a reference to the service project where the interface is
- using just the interface name without the namespace